# How to add data labels on a chart?

Tags: charts, label, gnumeric

I would like to add data labels for some values like "TIMEOUT" on bar chart in Gnumeric. As in the image below with "Not supported" string:

[image: chart with data label]

I know it is possible in Excel, but is it possible in Gnumeric, and how?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with doing opening chart preferences and doing +Add > axis line to X-Axis1, and then setting the ticks and labels under the given tabs. Can't get it to work though